# Cycloid on manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, differential-equations

Inspired by differential equation
$$y(1+y'^2)=c$$

which generates [the  cycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid#:%7E:text=In%20geometry%2C%20a%20cycloid%20is,curve%20rolling%20on%20another%20curve.) we  consider the following differential equation on a  Riemannian manifold:

$$f(1+|\nabla f|^2)=c$$

On the  other hand the  classical  cycloid has some  singularities(non smooth points).

This  motivates the following question:

> Is  there an example of  a Riemannian manifold which admits a globally  smooth non constant cycloid function?

Comment: Why not just restrict the cycloid to a subinterval on which it loses the singularities?

Comment: @terceira thqnk you for your comment.yes but in the question i search for globally smooth solutions